# Regex in Python to match words with special characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have this code

```
import re

str1 = "These should be counted as a single-word, b**m !?"
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\w{1,15}', str1)

print(match_pattern)
```

I want the output to be:

```
['These', 'should', 'be', 'counted', 'as', 'a', 'single-word', 'b**m']
```

The output should exclude non-words such as the "!?" what are the other validation should I use to match and achieve the desired output?

Comment: Non regex solution: `str1.strip(string.punctuation).replace(',','').split()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use word boundaries (`\b`) filled with 1 or more non-space:

```
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b\S+\b', str1)
```

result:

```
['These', 'should', 'be', 'counted', 'as', 'a', 'single-word', 'b**m']
```

`!?` is skipped thanks to word boundary magic, which don't consider that as a word at all either.

Comment: `\S` will also match `!?`

Comment: @tripleee in theory yes, but it works. Hmmmm it's the word boundary which prevents this.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jean-FrançoisFabre!

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve a similar result not using RegEx:

```
string = "These should be counted as a single-word, b**m !?"
replacements = ['.',',','?','!']

for replacement in replacements:
    if replacement in string:
        string = string.replace(replacement, "");

print string.split()

>>> ['These', 'should', 'be', 'counted', 'as', 'a', 'single-word', 'b**m']
```

Comment: `string.strip(element)` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like `[^\s.!?]` instead of `\w` but what exactly you want is not evident from a single example. `[^...]` matches a single character which is not one of those between the brackets and `\s` matches whitespace characters (space, tab, newline, etc).